# DRF: Always apply default permission class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions

When a permission is defined in a view, I would like to always check if the requesting user has that permission.

Let's say I have a basic permission check like this:

```
class HasPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view, obj=None):
        if hasattr(view, 'permission_required'):
            return request.user.has_perm(view.permission_required)
        return True
```

I have added it as default permission in my `settings`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'apps.api.permissions.HasPermission'
    ],
}
```

This works, but as soon as I define `permission_classes` inside a View, the default will be overriden. Is there any clean and proper way to do it? I could probably just write a Mixin and do the same inside `dispatch` but wanted to use the `Permission` classes as they were recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions attribute takes a list of classes so you just have to include the default.

```
class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (
        DefaultPermission,
        CustomPermission,
    )
```

Comment: I know, but I wanted to avoid having to add it to every class (there already are like 80), and always having to add it. Subclassing would make more sense in my case if there is no option that always applies the default class, even when defining your other permission classes.

Answer (score 0):

DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES will only be applied when you do not declare `permission_classes` in your viewset.

If you do not have any other permission classes that need to apply, simply exclude `permission_classes` from your viewset, that way it will always use the default.

If there is a time where you will need to use another permission class as well as the default.

eg

```
class HasPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view, obj=None):
        if hasattr(view, 'permission_required'):
            return request.user.has_perm(view.permission_required)
        return True

class AnotherPermissionClass(..):
    ....
```

where `HasPermission` always needs to be applied and sometimes  AnotherPermissionClass` may need to also be applied.

If this is the case, then just inherit `HasPermission` as a base class for `AnotherPermissionClass`.

```
AnotherPermissionClass(apps.api.permissions.HasPermission)
     def has_permmision(self, request, view, obj=None):
         has_base_perm = super().has_permmision(request, view, obj=obj)
         ...

class ViewsetA(...):
     ...

     # Don't declare permission_classes at all and it will use the settings default


class ViewsetB(...):
     permission_classes = (AnotherPermissionClass,)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Easier way of doing this is by appending any new permissions to the default classes.

This is more flexible because depending on the project, there could be APIs in the future which would have a totally different set of `permission_classes` (or maybe none at all).

```py
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings


class MyView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES + [permissions.IsAdminUser]
```

You could create a helper function so that it's easier to use

```py
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings


def init_perms(new_classes: list) -> list:
    return api_settings.DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES + new_classes


class MyView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = init_perms([permissions.IsAdminUser])
```

2. Explore extending the middleware for authentication or implement a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) which will run the default permission classes. If you want it to become more flexible, you may define a class attribute in the views e.g. `skip_permissions` and read that view class attribute from the middleware to know whether to run the default ones or not.